# Theme child on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm new on wordpress and I have readed about childs themes.

My question is, Is that neccessary that I create my self child theme or can I use other theme child created ? that's to say, if I use a child theme created for other person, that theme will not change that I do it?

Comment: if the child theme is for the same theme you can use it... otherwise you can't. If you don't need the same CSS you should clean the css file leaving only the commented part in the top of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way a child theme works is that it overrides the default settings of your chosen theme. So you only have to allow for the parts of the theme that you want to make your own.

As long as a child theme created for someone else is based on YOUR main theme, then you could use someone else's child theme.

For example, if someone has a child theme that works for Wordpress 2017, you can upload and modify that for your own use, for example to change the css or create your own header and footer files (usually named header.php and footer.php). These are the things I do most often.

If you don't already have a child theme for your chosen theme, though, it is best that you create one yourself. It is quite straightforward, all you have to do as a minimum is create a child theme folder with a style.css in the correct format and a functions.php file in the same folder using these instructions https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

If all you want to do is play with color and fonts, you might find it easiest to just use the Wordpress Theme Customizer. These changes will be maintained during upgrades in a custom.css file (or equivalent) so you shouldn't need a child theme.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am using proficient, which is a child theme of specia, can I modify then proficient without having to worry when they update specia?

Comment: Yes, that would normally be fine. The idea is that the child theme 'protects' you from main theme updates. If you modify a main theme you will almost always lose your changes, the child theme approach avoids this. 
The main time to be careful is when there is a major update of the main theme (specia) in case this means aspects of the child theme (proficient) are 'out of step' and no longer work. In this case the child theme provider _should_ make the impact clear to you before you take an update.